# CodeIgniter - Search results - How to return search results for specific word from multiple tables?

Tags: php, codeigniter

After I get a specific word from form. I want to get results like this word from multiple tables in database.

```
function search(){
    $search = $this->input->post('searchword');
    $this->db->select('articles.title, articles.post');
    $this->db->select('files.name, files.desc');
    $this->db->select('news.title, news.post');
    $this->db->select('projects.title, projects.desc');
    $this->db->from('articles, files, news, projects');

    // I think problem is here
    $like = array('articles.title' => $search,'articles.post' => $search,
    'files.name' => $search,'files.desc' => $search,
    'news.title' => $search,'news.post' => $search,
    'projects.title' => $search, 'projects.desc' => $search);
    $this->db->like($like);


    return $this->db->get();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI's joining is crap...

I always will create a proper sql statement with joins, and then just execute that.

```
$query = $this->db->query("BUILD A PROPERLY JOINED QUERY!");
```

If you're not able to do it yourself... build the query in PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench and make sure you get the results you'd expect.

Also, while I'm not a fan of CI's Active Record, have a look at this post to perhaps tune the join it's creating -http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/93198/

Comment: I agree with creating complex joins in a proper query, but even if you use CI's joins I am 99% positive it won't work the way the OP has it. You have to use $this->db->join, having multiple tables in the from wouldn't work since there is no way to join the tables described.

Comment: Yup... hence suggesting to use something to build it... I've always bypassed CI's Active Record stuff as soon as I need anything other than a simple select.

Comment: I did that. Thanks for answer.